# Matlab - the probability of five design variables

Tags: matlab

I am working on a problem where I have to generate a matrix of 32 rows x 5 columns of 5 design variables with upper and lower bounds. The design variables are as follow;

Lower Bound Upper Bound

> 0.51≤x1≤0.59
>
> 0.5≤x2≤0.65
>
> 0.05≤x3≤0.15
>
> 0.05≤x4≤0.20
>
> 0.02≤x5≤0.15

The probability of these variables is 32. I want to generate a 32x5 with a combination of these numbers

Is there any way to do that in Matlab?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: What matlab version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The 'rand' function will generate uniform random numbers between 0 to 1. The idea is to scale those values to fit inside your limits:

```
N=32;
LowerBound=[.51, .50, .05, .05, .02];
UpperBound=[.59, .65, .15, .20, .15];
Scale=(UpperBound-LowerBound);
%for newer matlab versions with auto expansion
M=LowerBound+Scale.*rand(N,length(Scale))
%for older versions
% M=bsxfun(@plus,LowerBound,bsxfun(@times,Scale,rand(N,length(Scale))));
```

Comment: Many thanks Mendi for the reply. In fact, I want to keep the numbers and use them to generate a 32x5 matrix. The lower and upper bounds are design variables. I want to make combinations and generate a matrix of these number.

Comment: This is not clear what you want. Write an example of output

Comment: I want to generate random numbers based on the Lower and upper bounds. In this case, we need to use probability in order to know the combination. For instance, 0.05  0.02 0.51 0.05 0.51 the second time the number could be 0.2 0.02 0.51 0.05 0.51 etc. In another word, all combinations of the elements (upper and lower).

Comment: It looks like that you ask how to pick up randomly 5 elements from 10 elements. I don't see how the definition of Upper and Lower has to do something with the generation of the matrix.